# Convert the default sub-category dashes to bullets or any other characters

Tags: categories

[image]We would like to convert / change the default Wordpress subcategories dashes (child categories) to bullets or squares or any other characters . So please do you have any idea how can we get that and which file or code should be updated (attached am image) to show the display area .. Thank you ..

Comment: Welcome to the site. Can you be more specific? Where are those dashes displayed? Chilled = Child ?

Comment: @birgire, hmmm I assumed he meant the admin

Comment: yes, you're probably right, I vaguely remember a recent question on similar things but for sub-pages. The dash there was hardcoded if I remember correctly and difficult to change it without javascript, I couldn't find it again. Don't have time to look into this now @MarkKaplun

Comment: the dashes displayed when adding new category then assigning category parent for example : 
Animal 
 - Cat
 - - White

Answer (score 1):

For the terms table in the `edit-tags.php` page, the extra level pads are added to the term's name in the `WP_Terms_List_Table::column_name()` method:

```
$pad = str_repeat( '&#8212; ', max( 0, $this->level ) );

/**
 * Filters display of the term name in the terms list table.
 *
 * The default output may include padding due to the term's
 * current level in the term hierarchy.
 *
 * @since 2.5.0
 *
 * @see WP_Terms_List_Table::column_name()
 *
 * @param string $pad_tag_name The term name, padded if not top-level.
 * @param WP_Term $tag         Term object.
 */
 $name = apply_filters( 'term_name', $pad . ' ' . $tag->name, $tag );
```

**Example:**

Here's one approach replacing the `&#8212;` dash with e.g. a bullet, with the `term_name` filter:

```
add_filter( 'term_name', function( $name, $tag )
{
    if( did_action( 'load-edit-tags.php' ) )
        $name = str_replace( '&#8212;', '&#8226;', $name ); //Adjust to your needs! 

    return $name;
}, 10, 2 );
```

Note that here we restrict it to the `edit-tags.php` screen.

Comment: I would like to thank you so much for your solution , it works very well .. God Bless You

Comment: Glad to hear it worked for you. The normal process is to accept answers ([see here how](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/270140)) if they solved the problem and to help other users with a similar question to see it's resolved. It also reduces the stack of open questions. Thanks @ShadiYounis